# How to cut a line in python?

Tags: string, python-2.7

```
2331,0,13:30:08,25.35,22.05,23.8,23.9,23.5,23.7,5455,350,23.65,132,23.6,268,23.55,235,23.5,625,23.45,459,23.7,83,23.75,360,23.8,291,23.85,186,23.9,331,0,1,25,1000,733580089,name,,,
```

I got a line like this and how could I cut it? I only need the first 9 variable like this:

```
2331,0,13:30:08,25.35,22.05,23.8,23.9,23.5,23.7,5455
```

the original data i save as txt.file, and could I rewrite the original one and save?

Answer (score 2):

Use either `csv` or just to straight file io with string `split` function

For example:

```
import csv
with open('some.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row[:9]
```

or if everything is on a single line and you don't want to use a csv interface

```
with open('some.txt', 'r') as f:
    line = f.read()
    print line.split(str=",")[:9]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your values are stored in an Array, you can slice like this:

```
arrayB = arrayA[:9]
```

To get your values into an array you could split your String at every ","

```
arrayA = inputString.split(str=",")
```

Comment: Looking at the way he formatted the "first 9 variables" this won't do. Slicing a string like this returns the first 9 characters, not the first 9 values that are separated by commas.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! My bad! I think it is time for Coffee. //Edited the code

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file called "content.txt".

```
f = open("content.txt","r")
contentFile = f.read();
output = contentFile.split(",")[:9] 
output = ",".join(output)
f.close()

f = open("content.txt","wb")
f.write(output)
```